# What was the main cause behind Solana hack in August 2022?

Tags: wallet, security

It was reported in news that nearly 8000 Solana-based wallets were hacked this week which resulted in loss of over $5 million.

Has the cause has been identified? Was it some kind of vulnerability exploit, an inside job or a data leak? Does it affect any way safety of Solana blockchain itself?

Comment: I believe it was the fault of the wallet Slope who was leaking seeds. It is not fully confirmed yet and the details are a bit fuzzy at the moment

Answer (score 2):

At the time of writing a full detailed post mortem has not been released. Slope wallet has admitted some fault in the leaking of seed phrases.
As far as we know currently, the Solana blockchain itself was not the cause.
https://slope-finance.medium.com/slopes-official-statement-regarding-the-breach-b964e70af0d6